# how to reduce apk filesize for flutter build apk?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, apk

Want to know how to reduce you flutter apk files? Currently the files produced are quite large, usually around 80 mb. This is simply too large for many purposes and it may help you to reduce the file size.

Answer (score 3):

Run `flutter build apk --split-per-abi`

This will build specific apk files for separate cpu architectures for mobile.

By default the apk that runs in emulator has a lot of debug libraries in it which increases the apk size by a huge factor.

Answer (score 1):

All the answers are valid
It seems not an instant solution, but the best approach is to follow the official flutter document for reducing the APK size, LIKE:

1. remove the unused dart packages from **pubspec.yaml**
2. Remove the unused assets like, images, gifs, sounds etc, or Atleast compress them
3. try to avoid boilerplate code as much as you can
4. use the central classes for constants instead writing the same code again and again.

Answer (score 0):

I am just sharing a small tip on how to reduce your apk file size.

**Go to: android/app/build.gradle**

and then under build types add these lines

```
buildTypes {
       release {
           minifyEnabled true
           shrinkResources true
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to flutter document, There is a option available for all platforms but not available for web so far.

This command will help you to get a minimized size of build except web

```
flutter build apk --analyze-size
flutter build appbundle --analyze-size
flutter build ios --analyze-size
flutter build linux --analyze-size
flutter build macos --analyze-size
flutter build windows --analyze-size
```